# CodeIgniter PHP echo data from Mssql query result with wrong characters

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, special-characters

I am using CodeIniter, there is database configuration file, in which I set parameters for my main mysql database - it works fine. Also I have anohter database (Mssql), I can connect to it, get data. Problem is when I want to create "Select" input and add data with value of "ID" and option name of "Name" column. Simple name values are okey, but there is problem with some specific language chars - with them output is �. I changed encoding to UTF8 in whole page, used utf8_encode function from Mssql result strings, but still there is problem, because chars are incorrect (after utf8_encode � chars changed, but not correctly).

Comment: What is the encoding of the table and row ?

Comment: UTF8 - there is no problem when I display data in test page. Problem with chars appears, when I want to add it to Select.

Comment: Then it is maybe the encoding used on the socket between MySQL and PHP, try mysqli::set_charset http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: check your charset in database

Comment: Charsets are set okey.

Comment: Found problem, but can't understand why:
My page in head tag has meta in which I said, that charset is UTF8. Whole page has it, I can see all special chars, except in select tag. But funny thing is that, when I remove these meta tags, right chars appears in select and whole page have wrong ones.

Comment: Perhaps because browser figures charset itself, try loading page in different browsers (hint: Internet Explorer).

Comment: There is no difference between browser I use, same bad chars.

Answer (score 0):

i am also having trouble regarding this error, but i solved it by adding this code before i query.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible to fix MYSQL problem by this, but I am using MSSQL database and it is different one.

Comment: `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');` did you try this?

Comment: Yes, tied, but it does nothing (tried everywhere: main page, in fuction and so on).